# Connect to VPN Server from only my Android App NOT the whole device

Tags: android, client, vpn

I have set up a VPN Server in an amazon ec2 server using softether (https://www.softether.org/) and want to route all the traffic from my android app through this server.

But all the solutions I have seen thus far use the vpn service class http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/VpnService.html, which creates a vpn tunnel for the whole device and not just my application. I want the other apps running on the phone to use the internet as normal while the traffic from my app is routed through my ec2 server.

Also this way if another app wants to start a vpn connection, my connection will be terminated as there can only be one connection and no simultaneous ones.

Is there anyway to do this? I am very grateful for any suggestions.

Cheers!

Comment: found any solution ?

Comment: @Oli sadly not :-/

Comment: But i found one, i think ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39330640/1274875